# FragmentPagerAdapter doesn't inflate fragments when added the second time (on custom view)

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I have a custom view extending RelativeLayout, in which I have a viewpager, much like [this card](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_9/0Bzhp5Z4wHba3cXJ0OTI1MXJUV0U/components_cards_action5.png).

**Problem:** When I first add the view into a layout everything is good, but when I leave the current fragment and go back to it, the FragmentPagerAdapter doesn't have any fragments on it. All the methods get called, but the fragments don't get inflated

**Custom view and adapter:**

```
SectionsPagerAdapter adapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(((MainActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

-

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return Fragment_HourlyPage.newInstance();
            case 1:
                return Fragment_HourlyPage.newInstance();
            case 2:
                return Fragment_HourlyPage.newInstance();
            case 3:
                return Fragment_HourlyPage.newInstance();
            case 4:
                return Fragment_HourlyPage.newInstance();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "10AM - 11AM";
            case 1:
                return "11AM - 12AM";
            case 2:
                return "12AM - 1PM";
            case 3:
                return "1PM - 2PM";
            case 4:
                return "2PM - 3PM";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Adding the custom view into the layout:**

```
//inside AsyncTask
CardActivityMonitoring card = new CardActivityMonitoring(getActivity());
container.addView(card);
```

**Changing screen fragments:**

```
public void openDashboard() {
    Fragment_Tabs main = new Fragment_Tabs();
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainContainer, main)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}

//I'm switching between these

public void openSettings() {
    Fragment_Settings frag = new Fragment_Settings();
    fm.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.mainContainer, frag)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

Replacing the FragmentPagerAdapter with a FragmentStatePageAdapter would fix this problem, but for some reason it would take 2 seconds to load the view.

I tried using a fragment instead of a custom view, but same problem.

Comment: Try removing `return null` from your `getItem`

Comment: That did not work

Comment: What is container in container.addView(card)?

Comment: It's a LineaLayout